# DLL references when using TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, version-control, dependencies, scrum

I am new to using TFS 2010 and was wondering the best way to add references (.e.g. AjaxControlToolKit, etc) to projects that I have added to TFS source control.

Would having the references be pointed to a shared folder on the network and being pulled from there be good solution? or is there a better way to achieve such things.

I have only ever used VSS with .NET stuff however have limited experience with svn/mercurial

Also - I would like to learn how to use TFS properly - does anyone have any useful guides or recommended reading? There are 5 developers in our company who have never had much 'proper' industry experience with team collaboration - however two of us are familiar with SCRUM and agile from university and would like to adopt this methodology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What we do at the company where I work is to place the dll in a solution folder (often named libraries or similar) and add them to the solution. That way they are added to source control automatically.

I'd recommend keeping dlls in each solution rather than a common share for all projects as different solutions may have dependencies on different versions of a dll. That being said, there's nothing to keep you from checking in all versions of all dlls you use in a common place in source control and then branch them into the projects where they are used.

Hope that helps.

### Edit: 2011-10-05

Since I've been getting some upvotes for this one I thought I'd fill you in on some small changes we are currently considering.

We are now considering setting up a private NuGet stream for the company and set up NuGet packages for each library or group of libraries. By including the packages.config file in source control we let NuGet do the work of getting the correct files. Instead of merging from the source whenever a new version of a library comes out, we just release a new version of the NuGet package.

In case some of the developers don't have NuGet installed it's supposed to be possible to include nuget.exe somehow and still get this setup to work.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - I wasn't aware of solution folders - I have only really worked on single project solutions with .NET - One query I have is when I've added this as a reference in visual studio the path is listed as E:\vs_projects\X\Libraries\AjaxControlToolkit.dll - does this mean when my colleague checks out the files they will have to have to check out to E:\vs_projects on there local machine for example? I hope this makes sense

Comment: Yes, if your reference points to a file path, then that file would have to be located at that path on every developer computer. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that if you put the dll file in the project, the solution will look for it using a path relative to the solution folder which would make it work for everyone.

Comment: I shall check it out after lunch - alternatively I was thinking of creating a virtual mapping that is the same on every developers machine so that it'll all work out :)

Comment: Worked perfectly without needing to map drives - thank you, this has been bugging me for ages of a suitable method to do this!

Comment: Cheers for the update! I've only recently started using NuGet a little bit but I love the ease of adding libraries it provided.

Comment: Thank you!  I placed my 3rd party dll files into a solution folder named 'Library' and referenced these dll files to the new location.  I can now successfully kick off a Build the TFS Server!